# Find text in xpath

Tags: xpath

How to access "Testing Field 1" from Label without using contains or adding span tag in Xpath

```
<label id="138:" for="136:" class="rcmFormFieldLabel">
  <span class="requiredField" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">*</span>
  &nbsp;Testing Field 1
</label>
```

my xpath

//label[contains(text(),'Testing Field 1')]/ancestor::div[1]//select

but my xpath have contains which i dont want

Comment: Have you tried any request ?

Comment: what do u mean......................

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: //label[contains(text(),'Testing Field 1')] but it having contains

Comment: Better add this to you post

Comment: now tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use these XPath-1.0 expressions:

1. This

   ```
   //label/*/following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]
   ```
2. Or this

   ```
   //label/text()[normalize-space()]
   ```

Result in both cases is

```
&nbsp;Testing Field 1
```